# Creating Google Forms from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-addons

It is possible to use the [FormCreator app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formcreator/lepgohlbinkefhmmblcjddfameifimbm) to create Google Forms using Google Spreadsheet.

My question: **how did app manage to achieve that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FormCreator app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formcreator/lepgohlbinkefhmmblcjddfameifimbm) was created using [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start). For more specific details see [Develop Add-ons for Google Docs, Sheets and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/)